# DragEvent, действие во время перетаскивания

Tags: android, drag-n-drop

Нужна ваша помощь.
Есть небольшое приложение, типа мозаики. Мы перетаскиваем изображение на другое изображение и если они совпадают, то происходить замена. Это если вкратце.
Проблема в том, что проверка происходит только на ACTION_DRAG_ENDED, т.е. когда мы отпускаем его. Как сделать проверку на перетаскивание, а не отпускание.

Вот кусок логики

```
public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {

    switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            if (dragEvent.getClipDescription()
                    .hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

            if (mPieceDragging) {
                mPieceDragging = false;

                if (dragEvent.getResult()) {
                    getTargetByRoundI(mRoundI, view).
                            setOnDragListener(null);
                    getTargetByRoundI(mRoundI, view).
                            setImageResource(getOutlineDrawableByRound(mRoundI, nGameName));
                    mRoundI++;
                    if (mRoundI < mRoundN) {
                        initRound(rootView);
                    } else {
                        dropAnimationView.setStopAnimation(false);
                        if (!dropAnimationView.getStopAnimation()) {
                            dropAnimationView.startAnimation();
                            dropAnimationView.beginTimer();
                        }
                        mHandler.postDelayed(mTickerDialog, 1000);
                    }
                } else {
                    mPiece.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    springAnimationX.setStartVelocity(500f);
                    springAnimationX.start();

                }
            }
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам разобрался. Засунул логику в ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED